# Find the index of the lowest unique value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to find the index of the lowest unique value in an input string with numbers ranging from 1 to 9.

I have two questions:

- Is there a better way to loop in comparison to the for loop I'm using? I'm not including the last element of the array since it'll throw an exception since I'm checking the value of the next element. I'm aware that it can be done if I include an if statement which checks if it is the last element but it will check on every iteration which is not optimal, hence I'm doing it outside the loop.
- Is there a better approach that I can use to find the result?

I am open to any remarks.

```
        string line = "3 3 9 1 6 5 1 5 3 6";

        // 1 array to be sorted in order to find the lowest unique value more easily
        // another array so I can get the index of the lowest unique value since 
        // the first array is going to be sorted
        int[] input = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
        int[] input2 = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
        Array.Sort(input);

        int? previous = null;
        int lowest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] != previous && input[i] < input[i + 1])
            {
                lowest = input[i];
                break;
            }
            previous = input[i];
        }

        int last = input[input.Length - 1];
        if (last != previous && lowest == 0)
        {
            lowest = last;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(input2, lowest));
```

Comment: Are the inputs always one digit? If they are then you could just compare the ascii values, no need to parse the integers

Comment: @Sayse Yes, they are one digit. As I said above, they are ranging from 1 to 9.

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit, then my comment stands. Also, your question may be better suited towards [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ and group the elements to get the count (uniqueness). Then find the lowest value.

```
int lowest = input.GroupBy(x => x, (k,v) => new { Key = k, Values = v }) /*group elements*/
                  .Where(x => x.Values.Count() == 1) /*get unique ones*/
                  .Min(x => x.Key) /*get the lowest*/
             ;
```

With this array it returns `2`, as expected:

```
int[] input = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: The title is a little misleading, I believe the op needs the index of the lowest value.  This finds the smallest unique value.

Comment: You mean the index of the int (so the nth integer), or the nth character?

Comment: Good question, hopefully the op responds.

Comment: I tested my comment using your code and it also works, (OP doesn't need to parse the list of ints, could always parse result if needed)... [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/e1ZvVO)

Comment: @Sayse: Thanks for the effort. Appreciate it.

Comment: Isn't this approach worse performance wise? The code that I posted already works but to clarify, yes I need the index of the lowest value. So with input array { 3, 3, 9, 1, 6, 5, 1, 5, 3, 6 }, the lowest unique value would be 9 since it's the only one not repeated and its index is 2.

Comment: @Ray: Not with small numbers. Besides, I don't think the performance impact it that big, but you could test.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I benchmarked your solution and mine. Yours took about 14 times longer. That's why I like avoiding LINQ as much as possible. But you are right that it's not an issue if the inputs are small.

Comment: Sorry to say, but how did you measure that? It is very hard to do a good analysis. (I have been doing this exactly for the last entire week, so I know how to mess up tests ;) ).

Comment: I used System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: That isn't very reliable. Did you check the code isn't JIT'ted in the mean time? There are a lot of factors in testing code.

Comment: I didn't but I ran the stopwatch a few times for each solution and the times were fluctuating very very little. Anyway, this is off-topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck in your approach is the sorting, not searching in the sorted result because `sort` is usually quicksort (O(n2) - worst case, but you are very likely to hit the average complexity O(n log n) ) and searching is O(n).

The problem you are trying to solve however does not require sorting, you can you it in one go by just looping through the values and counting (like count-sort does) - complexity O(n).

Comment: I could do it in one go if I was looking for the lowest value but if I want to do it for the lowest UNIQUE value it would become more complex, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `MinBy` LINQ operator (the Interactive Extensions provide one, but the quick version is below) and are willing to add a type
to provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation it can be done in a single pass thanks to LINQ's lazy operation and the overload of `Select` that passes the current index to the delegate:

```
var idx = input.Split(' ').Select((c, idx) => new IndexedObject(c, idx) })
                          .Distinct()
                          .MinBy(x => x.Value)
                          .Index;
```

Where

```
class IndexedObject<TValue> : IEqualityComparer<TValue> {
  public TValue Value { get; private set; } 
  public int Index { get; private set; }

  public IndexedObject(TValue value, int index) {
    Value = value;
    Index = index;
  }
  // Forward  IEqualityComparer<TValue> to Value
}
```

Helper, quick, non-error checking, version:

```
public static class EnumerableEx {
  public static TObject MinBy<TObj, TProp>(
                            IEnumerable<TObject> input,
                            Func<TObject, TProp> selector) {
    if (!input.MoveNext()) { return default(TObject); }

    TObject obj = input.Current;
    TProp theProp = selector(obj);

    while (input.MoveNext()) {
      var newObj = input.Current;
      var newProp = selector(newObj):
      if (newProp < theProp) {
        obj = newObj;
        theProp = newProp;
      }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: (Oops, hit save too early on this, initial version was incomplete.)

Answer (score 0):

For large arrays you should use a `SortedSet`.

Since you access elements at `i + 1` you should stop your loop earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 2; i++) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int[] input = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
int[] input2 = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
var tempIndex = input.Distinct().OrderByDescending(a=>a).Select(a => input2.ToList().IndexOf(a)).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(tempIndex);
```

and this is the debug result

> 2

Comment: @Ray Ozel Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: Doesn't this just return the indexes of the values when they are first come across?

Comment: @RayOzel What about now ?

Comment: It returns the correct answer now but as I commented on Patrick Hofman's solution, I avoid using LINQ because of performance issues.

Comment: @RayOzel! Good but if it is  helpful check it as a helpful answer. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

You should to store for every digits two values:

1. count of this digit;
2. index of first digit that found.

Then you'll can detect minimal element with `count` equals to 1, and get `index` of this element.

```
var line = "3 6 9 ... 9 0";
var input = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
var digits = new Tuple<int, int>[10];

for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    digits[i].Second = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < input.Lenght; i++)
{
    digits[input[i]].First++;

    if (digits[input[i]].Second == -1)
        digits[input[i]].Second = i;
}

int result = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
{
    if (digits[i].First == 1)
    {
        result = digits[i].Second;
        break;
    }
}
```

This solution gives you O(N) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This function return the index of the lower value in an int array:

```
int[] anArray= new int[] { 5, 40, 34, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int lowerIndex = getLowerIndex(anArray);

private int getLowerIndex(int[] input)
{
    //create temp array
    int[] sortTab = new int[input.Length];
    //copy array
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
    {
        sortTab[i] = input[i];
    }
    //copy array
    Array.Sort(sortTab);
    //get lower value 
    int lowerValue = sortTab[0];
    //get index of lower value
    int lowerIndex = Array.IndexOf(input, lowerValue);
    return lowerIndex;
}
```

Comment: Why would you load the value of the first element of the sorted array to an integer which is the lowest value and then look for its index after you just used the first index anyway? Also, my question is about the lowest unique value and not the lowest only.

Comment: In a sorted array, the value at the index 0 is the lower value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to hold the smallest value as the key and the index as the value.  It loops through the list just once.

```
string line = "3 3 9 1 6 5 1 5 3 6";
int[] input = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), int.Parse);
List<int> unique_values = new List<int>();
SortedDictionary<int, int> lowest_unique_values = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
   if (!unique_values.Contains(input[i]))
   {
      unique_values.Add(input[i]);
      lowest_unique_values.Add(input[i], i);
   }
   else
   {
      lowest_unique_values.Remove(input[i]);
   }
}

if (lowest_unique_values.Count > 0)
{
   // index of smallest unique value
   KeyValuePair<int, int> smallest_value_and_index = lowest_unique_values.First();
   Console.WriteLine(smallest_value_and_index.Key + " " + smallest_value_and_index.Value);
}
```

The resulting dictionary will also contain *all* unique values (sorted smallest to largest) and their respective index in the list.  The first value is the one you want.